# Confusion on PHP session.save_path

Tags: php

I have a PHP project that runs a user session perfectly on localhost. However, when I try to debug it on a server, it's not working properly. I checked where the session data is getting stored using the phpinfo

session.save_path

It appears to be getting stored in:

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php80
```

When I try to access this directory through cPanel I was able to visit that directory and when I use the "ls" command, I receive the following error:

```
/bin/ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

I'm confused about whether the session.save_path will have permission to save the session details there. Is this a problem?
I confirmed the path using PHP.ini. file

Session is not working on server but works on localhost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616). What exactly is the problem? The settings might not be the cause of the problem you have.

Comment: Keep in mind that the web server must have access to the directory, not your user account you are trying to run "ls" from.

Comment: So how do i know if webserver have a acess?

Comment: You can ask the administrator how the directory permissions and web server is configured. There are stuff like "chmod", groups and user accounts.

Comment: If PHP did not have proper access to the directory, then you should get an error saying so.